# yeoman with gulp-angular generator - ENOENT error

Tags: npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

Was trying to generate an Angular app with gulp tasks using this generator, after the generator has finished and bower and NP, had finished installing their dependencies as well, I got the following error message:

```
browser-sync@0.9.1 node_modules/browser-sync
├── path@0.4.9
├── commander@2.1.0
├── opn@0.1.2
├── dev-ip@0.1.7
├── browser-sync-client@0.1.9
├── ua-parser-js@0.6.2
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
├── http-proxy@1.0.3 (eventemitter3@0.1.2)
├── lodash@2.2.1
├── resp-modifier@0.0.4
├── cl-strings@0.0.5 (chalk@0.4.0, lodash@2.4.1)
├── gaze@0.5.1 (globule@0.1.0)
├── browser-sync-control-panel@0.0.5 (through@2.3.4)
├── portscanner-plus@0.1.0 (q@1.0.1, portscanner@0.2.3)
├── socket.io@0.8.7 (policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.6.7, socket.io-client@0.8.7)
├── connect@2.13.1 (uid2@0.0.3, methods@0.1.0, cookie-signature@1.0.1, pause@0.0.1, debug@0.8.1, fresh@0.2.0, qs@0.6.6, bytes@0.2.1, buffer-crc32@0.2.1, raw-body@1.1.3, batch@0.5.0, cookie@0.1.0, compressible@1.0.0, negotiator@0.3.0, send@0.1.4, multiparty@2.2.0)
└── url@0.7.9 (querystring@0.1.0, punycode@1.0.0)
execvp(): No such file or directory

events.js:72
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: spawn ENOENT
at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
```

Any assistance is much appreciated

Comment: I'm having this issue currently. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: rm -rf npm_componenets, and re-install everything over again

Answer (score 0):

*As the OP @Oleg Tikhonov noted in the comments:*

Remove the npm_components directory and re-install everything

```
rm -rf npm_componenets
```